# Powershell Compare column in csv

Tags: powershell-3.0

i'm trying to compare two csv files. And i want to check if there are objects that have the same name but different content but I don't know how i can do it. Can you help me please.

```
$File1 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\PM\Desktop\Migration\file1.csv"
$File2 = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Users\PM\Desktop\Migration\file2.csv"
$Tot_File = $File1 + $File2
Foreach($file in $Tot_File)
{
   $ident = $file.nom +  $User.prenom + $address.address
   Write-Host $file.Name -ForegroundColor White
   Write-Host $file.LastName -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
   Write-Host $file.Address -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
}
```

In output I have objects in duplicate. At the level of names I don't want the double.

Comment: `Import-Csv` can handle multiple input files, so you could do `Import-Csv file1.csv, file2.csv | Select-Object -Unique *` to get the unique records from both files. Group the output by name (`... | Group-Object Name`) to see if you have multiple records with the same name but different other data.

Comment: I try this code and it does not work: #Importing CSV
$File1 =  "C:\Users\PM\Desktop\Migration\file1.csv"
$File2 =  "C:\Users\PM\Desktop\Migration\file2.csv"

Import-Csv file1.csv, file2.csv | Select-Object -Unique *

Foreach($file in $Tot_File)
{
 
 $ident = $file.nom +  $User.prenom + $address.address
        
 Write-Host $file.Name -ForegroundColor White
  Write-Host $file.LastName -ForegroundColor DarkCyan
 Write-Host $file.Address -ForegroundColor DarkYellow
}

Comment: `file1.csv, file2.csv` -> `$File1, $File2` in that code, otherwise `Import-Csv` would be looking for `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` in the current working directory. For further help please [edit] your question with the modified code and more information about how *exactly* it "does not work".